# Ubuntu & Python: Time based scripting of multiple texts to speech

Tags: python, ubuntu, text-to-speech, speech

Wonder if anyone can help.

Here's what i'm looking to do: effectively write a "script" (as in a theatre / stage type production script), which has several voices/actors, saying different bits of text at different times. So there will be several voices all kicking off simultaneously all saying different things of different lengths.

What I'd like to do is program this on Linux/Ubuntu using Python, and I just wondered if anyone had any thoughts as to the best way to go about this?

Many thanks for any thoughts.

Cheers

Comment: This question is probably too general to be addressed on SO, and will likely be closed. A good question for your project would have been for example asking for advice between the audio library X and Y that you are considering for Z and Q reasons but that intend also to use in the W way... or advice on which pattern to use for a specific functionality or... Forums are a better place to ask advice if you'd like to receive a more free-wheel type of feedback. :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably are looking for running various threads with each one running an audio. I think is better you to read a bit of [threading](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/threading.html), or even [running parallel processes with Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing). For the Audio thing, there is a lot of  [python audio libraries](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio) that should help you. If I was looking for examples of this concept, I would for sure look for audio game engines.